# save only specefic connected components

Tags: matlab, components, filtering

From a gray image , I tried to extract all the connected components using bwconcomp, Then I work on each connected component. I want to draw in a new image with the size of the original image some specific connected components. I saw many works based on the area , the biggest component ... but for me I have new parameter that will filter the connected components, How can I draw in a new image with the original image size a specific connected component in its original place??
 Thank you :)

Comment: How do you "select" a specific connected component to begin with?  You need to know that before answering.

Comment: This question is not clear to me. Could you give an example code and an example of the desired outcome?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html#bu2xeh0-1) for `bwconncomp` includes an example of how to remove a specific component from an image. Adding components to a new image based on this should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to take a labeled map of connected components and do something to each component individually.

You can do this by [finding array elements that meet a condition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html).

Suppose you have labeled components such that your matrix, `mylabels` is

```
1 1 1 2 2 2
1 1 3 3 3 2
1 3 3 3 4 4
5 5 5 5 4 4
```

To select a specific region, 3 for example, use

```
regionA = (mylabels == 3);
```

That will produce a map of just region 3 like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You can use this map as a mask to isolate specific parts of the original image:

```
subimage = image .* regionA;
```

You can combine multiple connected components by combining their maps together

```
regionAB = regionA | regionB;
```

or by selecting multiple labels

```
regionAB = (mylabels == 3 | mylabels == 4);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply,how to know the label of the connected component ??
for l=1: CC.NumObjects
       if (sthing)
          keep this connected component
       else
          remove it 
       end
  end